# Is there any way to get the coordinates of a word using PDF::Report?

Tags: perl, pdf

I am using the [`PDF::Report`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::Report) module.

I tried this but I am not getting any text position.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use PDF::Report;

my $filename = "pdffile.pdf";
my $pdf      = new PDF::Report(File => $filename);

my $pages = $pdf->pages();
print "$pages \n";

my $fname = $pdf->getFont();
print "$fname \n";

my $String = "APRÈS ";

my $string_w = $pdf->getStringWidth($String);
print "$string_w \n";

my ($hPos, $vPos) = $pdf->getAddTextPos($String);
print "$hPos & $vPos \n";
```

Comment: You need to clarify what you want to do. Please [edit] your question. Do you want to read an existing PDF and get the coordinates in relation to the page dimension of an existing text in that document, or do want something else that involves a new, empty PDF file?

Comment: i need to get the coordinates of each and every  character in existing pdf file... @simbabque

Answer (score 1):

The [`PDF::Report`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::Report) module is for *creating* PDF files. It keeps a current horizontal and vertical position where text will be added with calls to `addText` will be placed. That is the position that is returned by `getAddTextPos` (and may be modified with `setAddTextPos`)

It's unclear what you mean by *"get the coordinates of a word"*. `getAddTextPos` doesn't take any parameters, and will return the coordinates where the *next* word will be added unless word wrap is invoked

Comment: thank you Borodin...i tried that getAddTextPos but showing error                  Use of uninitialized value $hPos in concatenation (.) or string at pdf_report.pl line 34.

Comment: @selva: I don't see any way around those warnings without editing the module file. The documentation invites you to omit some call parameters, but the code just checks them directly with a regex pattern without first making sure they're undefined. I think it's just a very badly-written module. Note that the superclass `PDF::API2` has the rather worrying line `no warnings qw[ deprecated recursion uninitialized ]`

Comment: thank you..if you have any any idea about how  to get the position of each and every character in existing pdf file means kindly share...@Borodin